# Getting week number in PowerPoint

Tags: vba, function, excel, powerpoint

I have got a code to generate PowerPoint with an Excel file. I have mostly modified the code as per my requirement, but I want to add one more feature into my .ppt. I want VBA to extract Week Number from some source and do the following:

1. Rename my .ppt as "XXX_Weeknumber.ppt"
2. In one of the textboxes in the slides I want to add the same Weeknumber.

I tried getting the week number by using the function WeekNum and trying to call the function in my Main Sub but unfortunately doesn't work!

My code for function in Module 1:

```
Function WeekNum(D As Date) As Integer
WeekNum = CInt(Format(D, "ww", 2))
End Function
```

Code for the .xls to .ppt in Module 2:

```
Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTShape2 As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim PPSlide As PowerPoint.slide
Dim SlideNum As Integer
Dim rng As Range
Dim WeekNumm$


Sub PPTableMacro()
Dim sourcexl As Workbook

Dim wk As Integer

Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
strExcelFilePath = "C:\MySource.xls"
strPresPath = "C:\Presentation1.ppt"
Call WeekNum
WeekNumm = WeekNum()
Set wk = WeekNumm
strNewPresPath = "C:\Presentation1_" & wk & ".ppt" 'This is how I want the name
strNewPresPath = "C:\new1.ppt"

Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue

Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
SlideNum = 2

oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("Table 1")

Set sourcexl = Workbooks.Open(strExcelFilePath) 'Source excel file
With sourcexl
.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 1).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 2).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(1, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(1, 3).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 1).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 1).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 2).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 2).Text
oPPTShape.Table.Cell(2, 3).Shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Cells(2, 3).Text

End With

Set oPPTShape2 = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("TextBox 1")
Text1 = "weekXX" ' actually wanted week number here
oPPTShape2.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = Text1

oPPTFile.SaveAs strNewPresPath
'oPPTFile.Close
'oPPTApp.Quit

Set oPPTShape = Nothing
Set oPPTFile = Nothing
Set oPPTApp = Nothing

MsgBox "Presentation Created", vbOKOnly + vbInformation

End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

Your function asks for a data input ("D"), and it's not optional. If you want to retrieve the day of the week of today ("Date" system variable), you should call it like this:

```
WeekNumm = WeekNum(Date)
```

Also, you are using a Set statement in "Set wk = WeekNumm". As the variable isn't an object, you have to use (a preferably omitted) Let.

Also, your function will not return the day of the week, because "ww" means the week number of the year. If you want the day of the week by this approach, you have to use "w".

For a better approach, you should use the builtin function [Weekday](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/82yfs2zh(v=vs.90).aspx) to get the weekday.

Like:

```
iWeekDay = Weekday(Date,vbUseSystemDayOfWeek) 'Retrieves today's day of the week (Tuesday = 3...)
```

Comment: Hi Israel, Thanks for your reply.
I would like to clarify, I want the week number of the year. for eg:assuming todays date 21st of October would mean that Week Number = 43. 
Also could you please let me know where should I place the code?

Comment: You mean your function? Or your entire code? A function it's usually placed inside a module, that way you can access it anywhere (userforms, another modules, classes, worksheet's code). As for the whole code, you can have an ideia from here: [link](http://www.contextures.com/xlvba01.html).... You can also make a VBScript from it, and run it independently outside the office platform. There is also a compiler for it: [link](http://www.vbsedit.com/)

Comment: I meant placing the 'line' of code/function if anyone could suggest me for getting the week number.
Well, anyways I have done it the easy way...
I have simply referenced the Weeknumber from the regular Excel formula in the sheet and its working without any issues. Thanks for your patience .. Cheers :)